# call activex methods

Tags: c++, activex

i have an ocx file and i want to use it in a win32 application, so i `change USE of MFC` to `USE MFC in a Static Library` and i proceed like this:

```
#import "C:\\Program Files\\GeoSDK\\LiveX_8300.ocx"
int CALLBACK WinMain(
   HINSTANCE hInstance,
   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
   int nCmdShow)
{

   // Register our Window class
   WNDCLASS wndclass;
   wndclass.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
   wndclass.lpfnWndProc = &WindowProc;
   wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
   wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
   wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
   wndclass.hIcon = NULL;
   wndclass.hCursor = NULL;
   wndclass.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast <HBRUSH> (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
   wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
   wndclass.lpszClassName =windowClassName;
   ::RegisterClass(&wndclass);

   // Create our main, raw win32 API window
   // We create the window invisible (meaning that we do not provide WS_VISIBLE as the window style parameter), because making it visible and then
   // adding a HwndSource will make it flicker.
   HWND mainWindow = ::CreateWindow(
      windowClassName,
      windowTitle,
      0,
      CW_USEDEFAULT,
      CW_USEDEFAULT,
      windowWidth,
      windowHeight,
      NULL,
      NULL,
      hInstance,
      0);
   ::ShowWindow (mainWindow, nCmdShow);
   ::UpdateWindow( mainWindow );



//ocx
   //_DLiveX p;

    typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *PFonc)(IUnknown*, HWND,IUnknown**);   
    HINSTANCE hDLL2 = ::LoadLibrary(TEXT("atl.dll"));   
    if (!hDLL2) 
      return 1;   

    PFonc AtlAxAttachControl = (PFonc) ::GetProcAddress(hDLL2,"AtlAxAttachControl");
    CLSID clsid = GetClsid();
    IID DIID__DLiveX = GetDIID__DLiveX();
    RECT rect;
    ::GetClientRect(mainWindow,&rect);

    container = ::CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT","",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,100,100,rect.right,rect.bottom,mainWindow,0,hInstance,0);
AtlAxWinInit();

    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL);

    LIVEXLib::_DLiveX *p;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid,
                    0,
                    CLSCTX_ALL,
                    DIID__DLiveX,
                    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&p)) ;


    if(FAILED(AtlAxAttachControl((IUnknown*)p, container, 0))){
                    p->Release();
                    return -1;
        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, "FAILED(AtlAxAttachControl(pitd, container, NULL))", "Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
                }

    while(hr == S_OK)
        p->CreateX();
```

when i excecute my prog i got activex attached to my wind but when i call any method i got this error `Unhandled exception at 0x752a812f in test1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0012fdbc..`
i know that i should call SetProperty methods or something like this but i don't know how

Comment: When you use #import then any failure HRESULT return code from a COM interface function is converted into an exception.  You have to catch the _com_error exception and use its methods to display the reason for the failure so you can diagnose the cause.  You will not know what's wrong until you add that code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MFC, use `COleControl`. The whole point of MFC is to provide classes so that you don't have to do everything yourself.

Comment: i create this method in a new class "CLiveX": BOOL CLiveX::CreateX()
{
 BOOL result;
 InvokeHelper(0x17, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_BOOL, (void*)&result, NULL);
 return result;
}  but i don't how use it

Comment: How is that connected to `COleControl` ?

Comment: that's my mystery, how can i connect to the COleControl from my main and call CLiveX Methods

Comment: @SIDAOUIMejdi: If you still have problems using one class from another, you shouldn't be trying to use ActiveX yet. Pick up a good C++ book first.